# Repair windows 7 software RAID

Tags: windows-7, raid, data-recovery

Sorry that some of this is vague, I wasn't onsite when it happened and am preparing to go in tomorrow and try to fix things.

We had a Windows 7 PC that had 2 disks in a software RAID configuration.  I don't even know for certain if it was RAID 0 or 1, I'm assuming RAID 1 (mirrored).

The two disks were taken out of the PC and put into a new PC.  The new PC was booted from its own, fresh Windows 7 install.  The 2 RAID disks were not recognized as members of RAID set in the new PC - one showed as a an emptry drive, one showed as not having been initialized.

When the disks were put back into the original PC, they still weren't recognized.  :(

What we're after is just to get the disks (or just one disk) readable enough to copy any data files off of them - we don't care about getting the original PC to boot from them.

Based on other questions here and other searching, it looks like `diskpart` will do what I want, but I wanted to check if that's the safest tool to use and what the sequence of steps would be.

Comment: The *safest* thing to do would be creating a backup image of both disks before doing anything else. Any attempt at recovery has the potential to do further damage.